# CMake include precompiled library

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to get compiled project under QTCreator with CMake under Windows, I'm wonder how to add external library and its headers to my project. I have my CMakeList.txt as follows

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(opencl_info)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")
include_directories(c:\\AMD APP SDK\\3.0\\include\\)
target_link_libraries(opencl_info c:\\AMD APP SDK\\3.0\\lib\\x86_64\\OpenCL.lib)
```

I'm getting `"CL\cl.h - No such file or directory"` how to include it? for now with "hardlink"?

Thank you.

Under VS15 I'm running this project and it requires to have:

"*Additional Include Directories*" c:\AMD APP SDK\3.0\include\

"*Additional Library Directories*" c:\AMD APP SDK\3.0\lib\x86_64\

"*Additional Depandancies*" OpenCL.lib and th eproject runs.

I need to have *OpenCL.dll* within my path.

So I'm looking for the same/similar behaviour for QTCreator/CMake to include headers and libraries (*.lib,*.dll) for my project.

Thank you.

I have more opencl platfroms (nVidia, AMD) present on my machine, per using `FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCL REQUIRED)` its nVidia identified instead `Found OpenCL: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v8.0/lib/x64/OpenCL.lib (found version "1.2")`

How to tell CMake explicitly to find and use AMD?

Comment: OT: Its easier to use / instead of \\ for the paths.

Comment: Is there a CL folder inside of c:\\AMD APP SDK\\3.0\\include\\

Comment: Also CMake has a FindOpenCL module. For help type: `cmake --help-module FindOpenCL`

Comment: yup, under c:\\AMD APP SDK\\3.0\\include\\  there is CL folder.

Comment: what if I have multiple OpenCL (AMD-CPU, nVidia-GPU), how then FindOpenCL to choose which one to use?

Comment: You can likley override the folder in CMake-gui before you generate.

Comment: I'm in QTcreator, and text-editing CMakeLists.txt, - not using cmake-gui ...

Comment: I did override OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIR, OpenCL_LIBRARY, now can find headers but not recognizing opencl functions "undefined reference"

Answer (score 1):

In CMake spaces are **separators**. If you want to use string with spaces, enclose it in double quotes:

```
"c:\\AMD APP SDK\\3.0\\include\\"
```

Comment: thanks, now path is OK but `include_directories("c:\\AMD APP SDK\\3.0\\include\\")
LINK_LIBRARIES("c:\\AMD\ APP\ SDK\\3.0\\lib\\x86_64\\")
target_link_libraries(opencl_info OpenCL.lib)` getting error `cannot find lOpenCL`

Comment: just compile program out of cmake `gcc -Ic:\opencl\include\ main.c c:\opencl\bin\x86_64\OpenCL.dll -o main.exe` - just works...

Comment: Pass **full path** to the library in `target_link_libraries` call, like you do with `gcc`: `target_link_libraries(opencl_info "c:\\AMD APP SDK\\3.0\\lib\\x86_64\\OpenCL.lib")`. BTW, you do that in your original code (but without quoting).

Comment: am getting `:-1: error: error: c:opencllibx86_64OpenCL.lib: No such file or directory`

Comment: Hmm, backslahes becomes dropped for some reason... Then replace them with normal slashes, CMake is smart to understand that: `target_link_libraries(opencl_info "c:/AMD APP SDK/3.0/lib/x86_64/OpenCL.lib")`

Answer (score 0):

Partial success, I moved AMD APP SDK to another directory named as `c:\opencl\` 
which is shorten with no space in path directory

I included direcotries `include_directories(c:\\opencl\\include\\)` and now an issue of missing `"CL\cl.h - No such file or directory"` is gone.

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly, answers are not supposed to contain other questions, so it's likely to get downvoted. That being said, just use double quotes, as well as forward slashes: `include_directories("c:/AMD APP SDK/3.0/include")`

Answer (score 0):

I found solution :)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(opencl_info)

include_directories("c:\\AMD APP SDK\\3.0\\include\\")
link_directories("c:\\AMD APP SDK\\3.0\\lib\\x86_64\\")
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")
target_link_libraries(opencl_info OpenCL.lib)
```

Thanks for help, guys!!!